# Python: How to use the function nd.Hessiandiag on a complex function

Tags: python, optimization, hessian-matrix

I want to use the function `Hessiandiag` from the package ([Numdifftools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Numdifftools)) to get the diagonal elements of an Hessian matrix using the optimal parameters that minimizes a function.

Here's a simple example of the usage of `Hessiandiag` taken from developers website of Numdifftools:

```
import numpy as np
import numdifftools as nd
fun = lambda x : x[0] + x[1]**2 + x[2]**3
ddfun = lambda x : np.asarray((0, 2, 6*x[2]))
Hfun = nd.Hessdiag(fun)
hd = Hfun([1,2,3]) # HD = [ 0,2,18]
```

Say that my function that I want to get the Hessian matrix is too complex to be written using `lambda`. My function is stored in another file under the name `Latent` (using the `def Latent(x1, x2, x3)` command). I **can't** do the following:

```
from Latent import Latent  # That's my function
import numpy as np
import numdifftools as nd
fun = lambda x1, x2, x3 : Latent(x1, x2, x3)
Hfun = nd.Hessdiag(fun)
hd = Hfun([np.array([1.2, 1.5, 2]), np.array(3.4, 5), 6])  # three parameters
```

...this doesn't work...

```
This is the error:

    raise ValueError('%s must be scalar, one of [1 2 3 4].' % name)

ValueError: n must be scalar, one of [1 2 3 4].
```

How can I use nd.Hessdiag with my complex function without using `lambda`?

**UPDATE**
I have also tried this:

```
fun = lambda x: Latent(x[0], x[1], x[2])
Hfun = nd.Hessdiag(fun)
hd = Hfun([x1, x2, x3])
```

I get this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\chamar.stu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 601, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\chamar.stu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 66, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "F:/dropbox/Dropbox/Research/Fisher Martineau Sheng/SEC/codes/Python Latent Factor/V1/Main_v1.py", line 101, in <module>
    hd = Hfun(np.array([est_param, allret_.T, n, capt, num_treat]))

  File "C:\Users\chamar.stu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numdifftools\core.py", line 1161, in __call__
    return self.hessdiag(x)

  File "C:\Users\chamar.stu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numdifftools\core.py", line 1171, in hessdiag
    dder, self.error_estimate, self.final_delta = self._partial_der(x)

  File "C:\Users\chamar.stu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numdifftools\core.py", line 830, in _partial_der
    self._x = np.asarray(x0, dtype=float)

  File "C:\Users\chamar.stu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 460, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work" please. Crashes, throws an exception (copy-paste the traceback), produces unexpected results, ??

Comment: Also, "`import Latent`" will not work if "My function is stored in another file under the name Latent"; you'll need to import the function `from` that module.

Comment: it probably needs to take 1 input variable instead of 3. Like it does in the example. `fun = lambda x : Latent(x[0], x[1], x[2])`

Comment: @Evert I update my question with the error that I receive

Comment: @M4rtini Tried... no changes. See my updated question

Comment: From a quick look at the code, there should be more traceback than just the few (one) lines you listed. Is that really all you get as the error message?

Comment: The second version (the updated one) appears to be correct; where does the second error originate? I'm guess from your `Latent` function, not from numdifftools. Again, provide the full traceback.

Comment: @Evert I posted my full error output

Comment: I think we'll also need your `Latent` function. Or at least know what type of value it returns.

Comment: But: usually this error occurs when you're trying to create an array from something that isn't a regular array/list, like `[[1], 2, 3]`. In your updated code, what are `x1`, `x2` and `x3`. Are they scalars, or are (some) arrays or lists with unequal sizes?

Comment: Sorry for the stream of comments, but I just noticed in your initial example that fails, you use `x = [np.array([1.2, 1.5, 2]), np.array(3.4, 5), 6]`, so `x1` and `x2` are indeed arrays of size 3 and 2, and `x3` is a scalar. That simply won't work. At a guess, that won't even work mathematically (I guess your input will have to be some rectangular matrix).

Comment: @Evert I see ... yes it is true that I am supplying arrays for `x1` and `x2`. Because my `Latent` function minimizes a function where I have to supply actual data into my function...that's why I have arrays. It is hard to get the Hessian function in Python.